Electrolysis of water with biocompatible electrolyte?
I want to perform electrolysis of water in a bacterial solution for production of hydrogen and oxygen. I am wondering what electrolytes could work best for this? The requirements are that the electrolyte cannot be depeleted during the reaction.
Right now the only thing I can think of is MgSO4. Are there any other electrolytes I should be aware of?

One issue you will run into is that locally at the anode and cathode the pH will change due to the reaction. It is best to use a buffer with a strong buffering capacity to limit this effect.

I would rather check compatibility on microbiology side. Many bacteria may not be happy with abundance of Mg and lack of Ca, Na, K. I would choose a balanced, mixed electrolyte. // And last but first, they would be exposed to products of electrolysis, mainly changes of pH and oxidative stress.

It's doubtful most bacteria can survive electrolysis, except perhaps for some extremophiles, perhaps these: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/electricity-carrying-bacteria-lead-to-new-applications-and-new-questions/
